# Identity Server 4 Add a claim to a generated token

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServerTools to Generate a token:

```
private async Task<string> CreatePaymentsTokenAsync()
{
    var tokenLifeTime = 3600;
    var scopes = new[] { CoinbaseAuthConsts.PaymentScope };
    // Use in-built Identity Server tools to issue JWT
    var token = await _identityServerTools.IssueClientJwtAsync(
            CoinbaseAuthConsts.AuthorityClientId, 
            tokenLifeTime, scopes, new[] { "AstootApi" });
    return token;
}
```

How can I add a claim to the token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IssueClientJwtAsync` is](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/tools.html)

> an easier version of that for creating tokens for server-to-server communication (e.g. when you have to call an IdentityServer protected API from your code)

If you want more granular control over the token generated, use one of the overloads of `IssueJwtAsync`:

```
Task<string> IssueJwtAsync(int lifetime, IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
// or
Task<string> IssueJwtAsync(int lifetime, string issuer, IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
```

You may want to check the source code for [`IssueClientJwtAsync`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/63a50d7838af25896fbf836ea4e4f37b5e179cd8/src/Extensions/IdentityServerToolsExtensions.cs#L27) to see how the internal call is done.